# duplicate mediawiki between 2 locations

Tags: mediawiki

I have setup a private wiki (1.35.1) running on Ubuntu Mate which is a guest OS on VMWare Workstation 16.  I'd like to run this wiki at 2 locations (A & B) that are isolated (no VPN connection).  I will be the only user accessing since it is my private wiki.

I've got the wiki setup and running at location A and will simply archive the guest and bring it up at location B as an identical copy.

**Question**:  After I spend the day at location A (editing my wiki there), can i just simply copy the entire `/var/www/html/Mediawiki` folder and the entire `/var/lib/mysql` folder (MariaDB) onto a thumb drive and dump onto location B?

The intent is for these to be identical wiki's - synchronized by me (sneakernet) with thumb drive.

**UPDATE** - this is working well so far.  Below is how i do it.

1. Stop the mysql server - `sudo service mysql stop`
2. Copy (using [rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203846/how-to-sync-two-folders-with-command-line-tools)) all new or changed files from `/var/lib/mysql/` to my external share with:
   `sudo rsync -cavurt --delete --info=del,name,stats2 "/var/lib/mysql/" "/home/rp/shares/VM_share_ubuntu/wiki_sql_files"`
3. Copy all new or changed files from `/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.35.1` to my external share with:
   `sudo rsync -cavurt --delete --info=del,name,stats2 "/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.35.1/" "/home/rp/shares/VM_share_ubuntu/wiki_mediawiki_files"`
4. Start the mysql server - `sudo service mysql start`

Now, copy the new/changed files to the 2nd machine:

1. Stop the mysql server - `sudo service mysql stop`
2. Copy in (using [rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203846/how-to-sync-two-folders-with-command-line-tools)) all new or changed mysql files with:
   `sudo rsync -cavurt --delete --info=del,name,stats2 "/home/rp/shares/VM_share_ubuntu/wiki_sql_files/" "/var/lib/mysql"`
3. Copy in all new or changed mediawiki files with:
   `sudo rsync -cavurt --delete --info=del,name,stats2 "/home/rp/shares/VM_share_ubuntu/wiki_mediawiki_files/" "/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.35.1"`
4. Start the mysql server - `sudo service mysql start`

In those rsync commands note that the end of the *source* folder needs to be `/` and the *target* folder does NOT have the ending `/`.  The significance of that is explained in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203846/how-to-sync-two-folders-with-command-line-tools).

**UPDATE 2:**  If you modify the `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` file on one machine you will need to make sure to make the same update on the other machine.  e.g.  If you [change the file upload size](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads) from the default 2M or some other change that affects `php.ini`.

Comment: You are forgetting the database.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin  I thought it was under /mysql?

Comment: Yes, and copying `MediaWiki` directory will not copy the database.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderMashin , that is why my post shows both of those 2 folders. I was just wondering if I was missing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would mostly work as long as you set [$wgServer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer) dynamically. Pages that use absolute URLs and are loaded from cache would link to the wrong URL, but that should be very rare - almost everything uses relative URLs.

Comment: Thanks @Tgr, so if the wiki running at A has base of `http://192.168.2.5` I would set `$wgServer = http://192.168.2.5` on that machine? And do same at location B if it’s base was something other than 192.168.2.5?

Comment: That, or something like `$wgServer = WebRequest::detectServer();`. That does have some [security risks](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T232931) for a public wiki, but for a private one it should be fine.